# Multiple virtual inheritance and constructor call of base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

There is this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Bazowa
{
    int x;
public:
    Bazowa() : x(55){}
    Bazowa(int x_) : x(x_) {}
    void fun()
    {
      std::cout << x << "fun\n";
    }
};

class Pochodna1 : virtual public  Bazowa
{
public:
    Pochodna1() : Bazowa(101) {}
};

class Pochodna2 : virtual public  Bazowa
{
public:
    Pochodna2() : Bazowa(103) {}
};

class SuperPochodna : public Pochodna1, public Pochodna2
{
public:
    SuperPochodna() : {}
};


int main() {
    SuperPochodna sp; 
    sp.fun();     // prints 55fun

    return 0;
}
```

After execution of this program, it will print "55fun". What happened to constructor calls in class Pochodna1 and Pochodna2 - are they ignored? Why member 'x' of class Bazowa is set to '55', but not '101' or '103'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Virtual base constructors are always called from the final leaf class. None of the other constructors for the virtual base are called. In your case `SuperPochodna()` is calling `Bazowa()` and the calls to `Bazowa(int)` in `Pochodna1` and `Pochodna2` are not used.

See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.14 or just google "virtual base constructor".

Comment: The relevant bit in the standard (in draft N3290) is 12.6.2:10-11, which even has an example much like this one.